# Переменная для объекта

Tags: java, объекты, static

Недавно начал учить Джаву, сейчас набиваю руку - пишу разные программки. Столкнулся с проблемой.

Есть два класса: в первом конструктор с определением числовой переменной и функция которая эту переменную выводит, а во втором - класс main с созданием двух объектов первого класса и вызове функции из каждого объекта.

Вопрос в следующем - когда определяю числа конструктора в создании объектов, то переменная определяется не для конкретного объекта а для класса в целом (то есть при вызове к примеру трех функций из первого класса из трех разных объектов того же(первого) класса везде будет выводиться значение вставленное в последнее определение объекта). Извиняюсь за то что глупый вопрос но все же как реализовать определенный конструктор для каждого из методов?

```
public class q {
  private static int bb;
  public q(int v){
    bb = v;
  }
  public void run() {
    System.out.print(bb); 
  }
}


public class t {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    q yy = new q(3);
    q uu = new q(7);
    yy.run();
  }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код, пожалуйста, а то что-то ничего не понятно :)

Comment: первый класс
public class q {
 private static int bb;
public q(int v){
   bb = v;

 }

public void run() {
  System.out.print(bb);
 }
}

Comment: public class t {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  q yy = new q(3);
 q uu = new q(7);
 yy.run();
}
}

Comment: выводит 7 хотя в конструкторе задано значение - 3

Comment: Уберите слово static из поля int bb. И почитайте что оно значит)

Answer (score 4):

Вы используете статическую переменную:

```
private static int bb;
```

Модификатор `static` означает, что член класса с этим модификатором является общим для всех объектов этого класса. То есть для всех объектов этого класса создается единственный экземпляр этого члена. Все объекты этого класса совместно используют этот единственный экземпляр.

В строке

```
q uu = new q(7);
```

Вы присваеваете переменной класса `q` значение 7. Т.е модифицируете общую переменную для всех объектов класса `q`. Объект `yy` выведет модифицированную переменную. Если Вы желаете, чтобы для каждого объекта была свое, "уникальное" поле `bb`, то следует убрать модификатор static.